# Dedicated thread with application level scope asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

i have a scenario in which i have to observe another Rest application from my asp.net application,

1st Solution is that i have to dedicate a thread for it which will last as long as my asp.net application

is running [mean with application level scope] but how can i implement this solution ? can i dedicate

thread and start it when my application gets started......

And that thread also have to do operations on my DB

2nd Solution is that i can create another Windows Service which will observe for me and do tasks on my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i dedicate thread and start it when my application gets started......

Yes. What is the question? Starting a thread of where the application start override is (global asax).

> 2nd Solution is that i can create another Windows Service which will observe for me and do 
>   tasks on my DB.

Better. ASp.NET may have 2 appdomains at the same time - or more. You basically force a specific configuration which may come back later and bite you. Painfully.

A windows service will make sure there is only one instance. It also keeps running 24/7. The lifetime of a asp.net application.... is controlled by IIS and it may be down when uses it.